# How to obtain imaginary frequency polarizability?

Tags: electronic-structure, dispersion-correction, electric-field, polarizability, response-theory

I am trying to find a way to calculate $C_6$ dispersion coefficients for some atoms and molecules. In papers and textbooks, this quantity is introduced using the Casimir-Polder integral from the dipole polarizabilities of the interacting particles $A$ and $B$.

$$ C_6 = \frac3\pi \int \alpha^A(i \omega) \alpha^B(i \omega) d\omega $$

In principle, I am aware that there are some quite sophisticated approaches (TD-DFT, LR-CCSD) that are extended to calculate $C_6$ coefficients directly. What I am interested, however, is to evaluate the integral myself on a quadrature, by calculating the polarizabilities corresponding to specific frequencies.

The calculations at real frequencies are implemented in many quantum chemistry codes (see [Q-Chem here, for example](https://manual.q-chem.com/5.4/sec_EOMGRAD.html)) - but I am yet to encounter a code that can handle imaginary frequencies. I also don't see how it could be done in a reasonable way without messing up the Hermiticity of the problem. Therefore, I assume this direct approach is not necessarily the way to go.

Is there, then, any reasonable way to obtain an imaginary frequency quadrature to evaluate the $C_6$ coefficients directly?

Comment: Related (but it's about methods to obtain C6, C8, C10, etc. rather than to obtain alpha(iw): https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/63/5.

Answer (score 3):

I dedicate this answer to [Bob Le Roy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_J._LeRoy) and [Jim Mitroy](https://pubs.aip.org/physicstoday/online/10455/Jim-Mitroy) who passed away in August 2018 and August 2014 respectively. I was thinking about them a lot while writing this answer.

### Dynamic dipole polarizabilities at imaginary frequencies

The dynamic dipole polarizability $\alpha_{\textrm{dipole},m}(\omega)$ of a system in state $\psi_m$ with total angular momentum $J_m$ and energy $E_m$  can be calculated using the following "sum over states" (in atomic units and with $\hbar=1$):

$$
\alpha_{\textrm{dipole},m} (\omega) = \frac{2}{3(2J_m+1)}\sum _n \frac{\Delta E | \langle \psi_m ||D|| \psi_n \rangle |^2}{(\Delta E)^2 - \omega^2}\tag{1},
$$

in which $\Delta E = E_n - E_m$ for each state $n$, and $D$ is the reduced electric-dipole operator:

$$\tag{2}
D \equiv r \mathbf{C}^1(\hat{\mathbf{r}}),
$$

and $\mathbf{C}^1(\hat{\mathbf{r}})$ is the spherical tensor of rank 1.  I *mostly* used the notation from [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.3567) popular, recent and thorough review paper by Jim Mitroy, Mariana Safronova and Charles Clark (you can follow Eqs. 10, 11 and 13 with the ground state $g$ replaced by me with an arbitrary state $m$; then look at Eq. 22).

**If you want to do this yourself, you need the energies $E_n$ and wavefunctions $\psi_n$ of your system (as many as you can obtain: the more you obtain, the more accurate your calculation).**

If the input of the function in Eq. 1 is $\textrm{i}\omega$, then we get the following (the RHS is no longer a "function" of $\textrm{i}\omega$ because $\textrm{i}\omega$ was already inserted):

$$
\alpha_{\textrm{dipole},m} (\textrm{i}\omega) = \frac{2}{3(2J_m+1)}\sum _n \frac{\Delta E | \langle \psi_m ||D|| \psi_n \rangle |^2}{(\Delta E)^2 + \omega^2}\tag{3},
$$

which is exactly what we have in Eq. 76 of the aforementioned review paper.

### Dynamic multi-pole polarizabilities at imaginary frequencies

We can obtain $C_8$ or $C_{10}$ or $C_{12}$, etc. as follows (based on Eqs. 3-5 of [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1134/S1063776106020014) which I found by searching "dynamic" in the title's of Prosev's papers on Google Scholar, and I was looking at Porsev's Google Scholar page because I didn't find "dynamic" on Marianna Safronova's first page of papers listed in descending citation count on Google Scholar, so I would have checked Derevianko or Porsev next but Porsev showed up as her #1 collaborator):

$$\tag{4}
C^{\textrm{AB}}_{2n} = \frac{(2n-2)!}{2\pi}\sum_{l=1}^{n-2}\frac{1}{(2l)!(2l^\prime)!}\int_0^\infty \alpha_l^\textrm{A}(\textrm{i}\omega)\alpha^\textrm{B}_{l^\prime}(\textrm{i}\omega)\textrm{d}\omega,
$$

in which $l^\prime = n - l - 1$ for a $2^l$-pole polarizability, and $n=3,4,5,6,\cdots$, and:

$$ \tag{5}
\alpha_{l}(\textrm{i}\omega) = 2\Re \sum_n \frac{|\langle \psi_0 |T_0^{(l)}|   \psi_n \rangle|^2}{E_n-E_0 + \textrm{i}\omega},
$$

and the $T_0^{(l)}$ operators are the zero components of electric $2^l$-pole operator tensors for a system with $N$ electrons:

$$
T_i^(l) = \sum_{j=1}^N = r_j^l C_i^{(l)} (\hat{\mathbf{r}}_j),
$$

in which $C_m^{l)}$ are the normalized spherical functions (the notation is slightly different from my above section on ***dipole*** polarizabilities because I was basing that part on the review paper by Mitroy *et al.* and this part on the paper by Porsev and Derevianko).

### Casimir-Polder integral

I removed the part in your question in which you refered to your Eq. 1 as the Casimir-Polder integral, because that formula is quite different from what I see in the [1948 paper by Casimir and Polder](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.73.360). Eq. 1 of [this paper by James Babb](https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/9904050v1) is referred to as the Casimir-Polder integral in that paper and much more closely resembles what is in the 1948 paper, and also resembles Eq. 1 of [this paper](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.63.054101). Your Eq. 1 might be indirectly called the Casimir-Polder integral" by the OP of the CFOUR mailing list thread that I will mention below, but the aforementioned *research papers* by experts in the field do not call it that. Your Eq. 1 is called the "Casimir-Polder formula" in [this paper](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.jctc.6b00361) which uses TDDFT to calculate dynamica polarizabilities at imaginary frequencies, but it's not clear what software they used, so I will discuss software implementations in the seciton below.

### Software implementations

On 18 September of this year, on the CFOUR mailing list, a thread with the title "Dynamic polarizability function at imaginary frequencies" was initated, which asked whether or not CFOUR can do this type of calculation. John Stanton replied with the following input file for real-valued frequencies:

```
CH+ FREQUENCY-DEPENDENT POLARIZABILITIES USING CCLR
C
H 1 R

R=1.13092025572

*CFOUR(CALC=CCSD,REF=RHF,CHARGE=1,PROP=DYNAMICAL
LINEQ_CONV=10
CC_CONV=10,SCF_CONV=10,DIFFTYPE=UNRELAXED,SPHERICAL=OFF)

C:OLSEN
H:OLSEN

%frequency
1
0.1
```

and Stephen Coy provided another example of a dynamic polarizability calculation at a real-valued frequency (which also for some reason shows an automatic two-step augmentation of the basis functions):

```
CCSD/t-aug-cc-pVTZ calculation of pby at 694.3 nm for HF
F
H 1 R

R=1.7328

*ACES2(CALC=CCSD
UNITS=BOHR
MEMORY=50000000,BASIS=SPECIAL
PROP=DYN_POL,DIFF_TYPE=UNRELAXED
LINEQ_EXPAN=25
SCF_CON=9,CC_CONV=11,CONV=6,LINEQ_CONV=10)

F:T-AUG-PVTZ
H:T-AUG-PVTZ

%frequency
1
.06562473178260349867
```

but Stephan Sauer pointed out that these do not do the calculation at imaginary frequencies (if you can navigate the CFOUR code you can probably add imaginary frequency calculations as a new feature though) and that Dalton can do the calculation. The OP replied by saying:

> "My molecule is an open-shell radical, so either Dalton (coupled cluster part) or Molpro implementations do not work (as far as I know)."

[This is where the MOLPRO manual discusses dyanmic polarizabilities with frequencies that have a non-zero imaginary part](https://www.molpro.net/manual/doku.php?id=excited_states_with_equation-of-motion_ccsd_eom-ccsd#first-_and_second-order_properties_for_ccsd_from_expectation-value_cc_theory_xccsd) but that page does only mention "closed-shell" and not "open-shell". The following MOLPRO forum threads seem to discuss calculations of polarizabilities for closed shell systems: [this one](https://www.molpro.net/pipermail/molpro-user/2012-September/005045.html) is for H2O, [this one](https://www.molpro.net/pipermail/molpro-user/2011-January/004101.html) is for H2O, [this one](https://www.molpro.net/pipermail/molpro-user/2013-June/005440.html) is for N2-N2. [This one](https://www.molpro.net/pipermail/molpro-user/2016-April/006676.html) asks:

> "I would like to obtain polarizability for open-shell systems but first I am testing the finite field approach with DIP and QUAD field and comparing the results obtained with "polarizability" command"

but seems to have not received any response.